# ESP32 CAM failed to get frame in time

Tags: esp32, camera

So I think the title says it all. I recently purchased an ESP32 CAM in India for a pretty cheap price.

It looks like an AI Thinker but doesn’t have the tag on the chip itself. Nonetheless, to get it setup before my use case I decided to test the camera. I loaded up the CameraWebServer example and set my camera type to AI thinker.

The code uploads successfully and runs successfully. I can open up the IP address and it shows the page. However whenever I try to get a still or start a stream, it gives this error:

```
[E][camera.c:1344] esp_camera_fb_get(): Failed to get the frame on time!
Camera capture failed
```

It’s pretty annoying and this happens in both 5V power and 3V power. The camera does physically get a bit hot after loading the website. Oh yeah, I have an OV 2460 Camera attached to the ESP.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I just bought 2 esp32-cam-mb, one is working fine, the other gave error 1483, I swaped the cam with a spare one I had, and it is working.
Titi

Comment: esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
add this to your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for if this occurs on a known working ESP-32-cam with PSRAM (i.e. example sketch with face recognition works ok).
If you're using anything other than `PIX_FORMAT_JPEG`, try reducing `xclk_freq_hz`.
In my case, it suddenly worked fine with `PIX_FORMAT_RGB888`, `FRAMESIZE_VGA` and `xclk_freq_hz = 5000000` (4x lower).

( @Vraj P, this might not apply directly to what you found your problem was, but this post gets seen by many searching for this problem. Thanks!).

Comment: For me, reducing the XCLK frequency from 20 MHz to 10 MHz worked.

Comment: Over here, it was trying to compile with esp-idf `idf.py` with VSCode. Instead, compile esp32cam code with `arduino-ide`. Or use the arduino-cli compiler with VSCode for intellisense and a better editing experience. For some reason, the code compiled with idf is runnable but creates this error of not being able to get the frame on time, no matter what settings are used. xclk_freq_hz et. al.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried and tried to get the camera working. However, I decided to concede to the part of me that thought it was a hardware error. I purchased a new OV2640 module and instantly it worked.

I think I learned my lesson in purchasing cheap components. I inspected the old one further. Turns out there was a faulty ribbon cable. Anyways, I hope you aren’t in this situation. Seems like the only solution is to purchase new hardware, and the current issue is faulty hardware.

Comment: THIS is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is given here (scroll down to find this specific issue)
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-troubleshooting-guide/

There appear to be two sets of ESP-32-CAMs, one with and one without the PSRAM.

Comment: This is something that I did come across, but like I said, using a new camera module worked instantly. This probably meant that in my case it was a simple hardware error.

Answer (score 1):

Look I've just had that problem for a month and if you're using esp32- ov2640 look the camera reference because the one I've had was TY 0V2640-V2.0 and what I've saw it's like a cheap copy of the normal camera, so be careful. I had to buy a new one because everything looked like a broken image, although all the config worked fine. Even changing the `PIX_FORMAT` and `xclk_freq_hz` didn't work. The camera was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This stung me too. I found increasing the frame buffer count helped.

```
camera_config_t config;
config.fb_count = 10;  // Or some other number
```